# Android raw query problem

Tags: android

I have a database which has a column of dates in milliseconds. I'm trying to perform a query which allows me to retrieve only the dates that are greater than the current system time and in ascending order.

This is what I have done, but it doesn't seem to work, help would be most appreciative.

```
    long lowestDate = 0;
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    String CT = Long.toString(currentTime);
    String[] args = {CT};
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String mySQL =   " select dt" 
                   + " from reminders"
                   + " where dt > " + args[0]
                   + " orderby dt Asc ";
    Cursor c1 = mDb.rawQuery(mySQL, null);
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Is it crashing, are you getting an error message, is the result not what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

```
String mySQL =   " select dt" 
                   + " from reminders"
                   + " where dt > " + System.currentTimeMillis()
                   + " order by dt Asc ";
```

"Order by" not "orderby",  long to string cast is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

```
 long lowestDate = 0;
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    String CT = Long.toString(currentTime);
    String[] args = {CT};
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String mySQL =   " select dt" 
                   + " from reminders"
                   + " where dt > '" + args[0]
                   + "' orderby dt Asc ";
    Cursor c1 = mDb.rawQuery(mySQL, null);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 String mySQL =   "select dt" 
                       + " from reminders"
                       + " where dt > '" + args[0]
                       + "' orderby dt Asc";
```